# Whats the best way to get updates about an aws product?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-appsync

So I'm checking out aws appsync, and it's clear that it's under development. I really want to know about the latest changes and platform updates that might affect my work with the platform.  Is there an easy way to get updates about changes to a specific AWS service (in my case appsync), without getting hit by the firehose of all changes to all AWS products (of which there are tons)?

I know internally at Amazon there are all sorts of interest email lists, but obviously those aren't public.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't a one-stop subscription to a single service update, though that's an excellent idea.

You can [subscribe to the AWS what's new](https://aws.amazon.com/new/) page (though that might be the noise you were hoping to avoid), or you can [subscribe to the AWS Mobile blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/), which will house updates to the AppSync service. Unfortunately, both have extra noise, but at least the second option might be a bit more filtered down.

Comment: Thanks for the info Jeff!